# Datasets of misleading graphs

Tags: graph, dataset, image-classification

Im working on a project to test using image classification algorithms to classify graphs as misleading or not. Im trying to find any datasets of misleading graphs, however, I can only find a few websites with a small number of examples. I'm not sure if I'm just failing to find them or they don't exist, any help with this would be great!

Ive tried looking into previous research papers and exploring the internet and places like kaggle with little success.